# Renaming Grails Project in Netbeans

Tags: grails, netbeans, project, rename

I have a project that I would like to rename (I'm using Netbeans) and I can't find an option to do so. With a Java project it was as simple as right click project -> rename.

Is there a way to rename a Grails project? (Without causing issues with the classes therein)

Comment: The methods described applies to NetBeans in general, AFAICT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Close any applications which may be using the app (Netbeans, Grails run-app, etc..)

(2) Update your `application.properties` file to have your new application name.

```
app.name=youroldappname
```

(3) Rename the base directory where your project is to `yournewappname`.

Answer (score 7):

This has moved to the project.xml file in the most recent versions of NetBeans (I'm running 7.1).

1. open *[project directory]*`/nbproject/project.xml`
2. change the `<name>` to reflect the new name of the project:

`<name>[new project name]</name>`

Comment: Thank you for letting us know! +1